# How to disable irrelevant Windows Updates

Tags: windows, microsoft-office-2007, windows-update

I have Microsoft Office installed, but only Word, Excel and Powerpoint. I do not have Outlook installed, and do not use it. Or Windows Mail or something similar.

Nevertheless, Windows always wants to install a : Update for Microsoft Office Outlook 2007 Junk Email Filter

Why? How can I tell it to go away? Hiding he update does nothing as it will come back when there is a new one or if I reboot.

It also wants to install updates for Windows Defender, which I have removed and do not use.....

edit: I found this [site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830335/), which basically has no solution. I am scenario 2, and I want to avoid the update continually being recommended to me.

Comment: Which OS please? XP, Vista, or Windows 7? The settings are slightly different between them.

Comment: Really though, I say just install them, it's not gonna hurt anything. In fact you can set it to automatically install updates, then you wont even know.

Comment: davr, it happens on both 7 and vista

Comment: See the newly updated : http://superuser.com/questions/167898/how-do-disable-irrelevant-or-unwanted-windows-updates for the how-to with the Windows 7 Update Manager

Answer (score 3):

If you go to the [Windows Update site](http://www.update.microsoft.com/microsoftupdate/v6/default.aspx?ln=en-us) and select "Custom" it will search for all the updates it thinks you need. Find the one you don't want, expand the details by clicking on the <kbd>+</kbd> icon and then select "Don't show this update again".

Comment: I don't want to use the website though, I prefer my computer to notify me.

Comment: @Bill - you'd only have to use it the once (until the next one turns up of course).

Comment: The problem is that each update has a different id number, so I actually get a few showing up, at the very minimum of once a month, but often more than that. It irks me, and I should be able to disable this permanently.

Comment: @Bill - I didn't realise there were so many. I must admit that I accept all the junk mail updates despite not using Outlook, mainly due to laziness.

Answer (score 0):

This article by Microsoft Support might help:
[How to troubleshoot Windows Update or Microsoft Update when you are repeatedly offered an update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910339)

And, although it's not the same error, see the following article for how to remove the temporary update files that Windows uses to identify updates for your computer:
[Windows Update error 80070002](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Windows-Update-error-80070002)