# How do disable irrelevant or unwanted windows updates?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Windows keeps requesting to install the same updates that I have told it 'no' to several times, and it asks every time I turn my computer on.

How do I tell it 'Absolutely not. Never. No. Stop asking.' (the same answer you tell your immature teen when he requests to drive your porsche ).

**Before you press Close as Duplicate** The answers in [How to disable irrelivant Windows Updates](https://superuser.com/questions/55410/how-to-disable-irrelivant-windows-updates)  are *no longer relevant* - when you go to the windows update page, it tells you to use your windows update program (Start > Windows Updates) and the options he mentions are not there.

I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Windows Update, view the list of updates (by clicking on text like "1 optional update is available").  Right-click on each one you're not interested in, and select "Hide Update".