# Windows update keeps failing with a 13EC error

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update

I have windows update keep failing over and over on trying to install visual studio 2010 service pack 1. But what is interesting is that visual studio 2010 is not installed on the this computer. This makes all the updates fail. Its very annoying and any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's probably being offered to you since you have Visual C# 2010 Express (along with the bundled 2010 Express Prerequisites, Tools for Office etc.) Windows Update isn't that [intelligent](http://superuser.com/questions/485826/unnecessary-office-updates-being-offered).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was hoping windows update would be more smart. Oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this is either

- Not enough free disk space
- Windows Update being snotty with SP1

In the case of point 1, that's easy to sort, but I suspect that you have sufficient disk space available for that.

In the case of point 2, as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21702234/3831621), Windows Update is screwing up the updates, and the way to fix this is to use the stand alone installer from Microsoft, which can be found at: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691

Here is another point you might find interesting, again, from that same SO post.

> I had the same problem with later versions of Visual Studio (Visual
>   Studio 2012, Visual Studio 2013), when trying to install Service Packs
>   (SP2, SP3). Using the installer, it installed without problems.

Comment: I have over 300 GB of free space so its probably not the problem but the thing is that i don't have visual studio 2010 installed on this computer.

Comment: neither. I have the update installed though. It could be a "feature" of Windows that requires that specific pack.

Comment: I'll try the stand-alone installer

Comment: The stand-alone installer installed visual studio 2010 with it (???) so I guess i'm good. I still have no idea why i need visual studio 2010 anyway but who does?

Comment: it's probably a M$ update that broke something that could be fixed by SP1, so rather than write a new patch, they roll out VS2010 SP1 to every Windows machine...

Comment: Damn. On the plus side, it seems to have installed correctly